# How to pass a list of string to WebAPI get method/

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

My call from angular

```
 private apiResource = environment.baseUrl + 'api/Resource'; 

    getQueryUserPresence(userEmails: any[]): Observable<any> {
        let params =  new HttpParams().set('userEmails', userEmails);
        return this.http.get<any>(this.apiResource, {params: params });   
      }
```

My method in WebAPI. The userEmailsis a list however it is always null. for some reason. If I pass a single string and change it to just one string then it works. When I change to a list it is null

```
 public Team Get(List<string> userEmails)
        {   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('userEmails', 'test1');
params = params.append('userEmails', 'test2');
params = params.append('userEmails', 'test3');
return this.http.get<any>(this.apiResource, {params: params });
```

one more change you need on the Web API is to use FormQuery,

```
public Team  Get([FromQuery] List<string> userEmails)
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work. List<string> userEmails is still null on the webAPI side